# cmake find_package with specified location of the library protobuf

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

My project require protobuf 3.5.1, I built it and want cmake use it instead of installed in system (2.5.0). It is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(test)

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "/path_to_protobuf/lib/pkgconfig:$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Protobuf 3.5.1 REQUIRED)

link_directories(
        ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

include_directories(
        src
        ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS}

)

protobuf_generate_cpp(
        PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS
        ../my_proto.proto
)

set(sourceDir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
file(GLOB_RECURSE allFiles "${sourceDir}/*.h" "${sourceDir}/*.cpp")

add_executable(
        test
        ${allFiles}
        ${PROTO_SRCS}
        ${PROTO_HDRS})

target_link_libraries(
        test
        ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}
)
```

But cmake finishes with error message:

```
CMake Warning at lib_build/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:455 (message):
  Protobuf compiler version 3.5.1 doesn't match library version 2.5.0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:36 (find_package)


CMake Error at lib_build/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Protobuf: Found unsuitable version "2.5.0", but required is
  at least "3.5.1" (found /usr/lib64/libprotobuf.so;-lpthread)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  lib_build/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:376 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  lib_build/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:543 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:36 (find_package)


— Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/app/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/app/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

How to specify module search path correctly?
Can I do that without writing self FindProtobuf.cmake file?

Comment: The error message says, `Found unsuitable version "2.5.0", but required is at least "3.5.1"`

Comment: `find_package(Protobuf 3.5.1 REQUIRED)` specifies that `3.5.1` is the minimum. If you think the restriction is wrong you can try reducing the version requirement otherwise install a newer version..

Comment: My question: How to specify to cmake the path to find the correct version of the library? I built protobuf 3.5.1 from sources and install it to /path_to_protobuf.

Comment: And I can't install the updated version of the library in the system.

Comment: The question is not in a specific version, but how to correctly specify the path where cmake look for libraries

Comment: Usually, setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable to the library's installation prefix is sufficient for find that library. In your case, pass `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path_to_protobuf` option for `cmake` invocation. Do not forget to clear CMake cache (`CMakeCache.txt` file in build directory) before such reconfiguration.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thank you, your solution works, question closed.